# Apache Spark - accessing internal data on RDDs?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, checkpointing

I started doing the [amp-camp 5 exercises](http://ampcamp.berkeley.edu/5/exercises/data-exploration-using-spark.html). I tried the following 2 scenarios:

**Scenario #1**

```
val pagecounts = sc.textFile("data/pagecounts")
pagecounts.checkpoint
pagecounts.count
```

**Scenario #2**

```
val pagecounts = sc.textFile("data/pagecounts")
pagecounts.count
```

The total time show in the Spark shell Application UI was different for both
scenarios.
*Scenario #1 took 0.5 seconds, while scenario #2 took only 0.2
s*

In scenario #1, checkpoint command does nothing, it's neither a
transformation nor an action. It's saying that once the RDD materializes
after an action, go ahead and save to disk. Am I missing something here?

**Questions:**

1. I understand that scenario #1 is taking more time, because the RDD is
   check-pointed (written to disk). Is there a way I can know the time taken
   for checkpoint, from the total time?
   The Spark shell Application UI shows the following - Scheduler delay, Task
   Deserialization time, GC time, Result serialization time, getting result
   time. But, doesn't show the breakdown for checkpointing.
2. Is there a way to access the above metrics e.g. scheduler delay, GC time
   and save them programmatically? I want to log some of the above metrics for
   every action invoked on an RDD.
3. How can I programmatically access the following information:

   - Size of an RDD, when persisted to disk on checkpointing?
   - How much percentage of an RDD is in memory currently?
   - Overall time taken for computing an RDD?

Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Spark REST API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/monitoring.html#rest-api) provides almost all you are asking for.

Some examples;

> How much percentage of an RDD is in memory currently?

`GET /api/v1/applications/[app-id]/storage/rdd/0`

will be responded with:

```
{
  "id" : 0,
  "name" : "ParallelCollectionRDD",
  "numPartitions" : 2,
  "numCachedPartitions" : 2,
  "storageLevel" : "Memory Deserialized 1x Replicated",
  "memoryUsed" : 28000032,
  "diskUsed" : 0,
  "dataDistribution" : [ {
    "address" : "localhost:54984",
    "memoryUsed" : 28000032,
    "memoryRemaining" : 527755733,
    "diskUsed" : 0
  } ],
  "partitions" : [ {
    "blockName" : "rdd_0_0",
    "storageLevel" : "Memory Deserialized 1x Replicated",
    "memoryUsed" : 14000016,
    "diskUsed" : 0,
    "executors" : [ "localhost:54984" ]
  }, {
    "blockName" : "rdd_0_1",
    "storageLevel" : "Memory Deserialized 1x Replicated",
    "memoryUsed" : 14000016,
    "diskUsed" : 0,
    "executors" : [ "localhost:54984" ]
  } ]
}
```

> Overall time taken for computing an RDD?

To compute an RDD is also called either Job, stage, or attempt.
`GET /applications/[app-id]/stages/[stage-id]/[stage-attempt-id]/taskSummary`

will be responded with:

```
{
  "quantiles" : [ 0.05, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.95 ],
  "executorDeserializeTime" : [ 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0 ],
  "executorRunTime" : [ 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0 ],
  "resultSize" : [ 1457.0, 1457.0, 1457.0, 1457.0, 1457.0 ],
  "jvmGcTime" : [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ],
  "resultSerializationTime" : [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ],
  "memoryBytesSpilled" : [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ],
  "diskBytesSpilled" : [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ],
  "shuffleReadMetrics" : {
    "readBytes" : [ 340.0, 340.0, 342.0, 342.0, 342.0 ],
    "readRecords" : [ 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0 ],
    "remoteBlocksFetched" : [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ],
    "localBlocksFetched" : [ 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0 ],
    "fetchWaitTime" : [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ],
    "remoteBytesRead" : [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ],
    "totalBlocksFetched" : [ 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0 ]
  }
}
```

Your question is too broad, hence I will not respond to all. I believe everything spark has to reflect is reflected with the REST API.

Comment: I understand my question is broad and thanks for your answer. Can I use the REST api, while the application is running?

Comment: Yes. Actually, with self-contained applications, you can only access the REST API while your application is running. After application terminates, API server will terminate with it.

Comment: I get it now. I was trying to access the REST api, after my application had stopped. If that's the case, how can I access the application ID, inside my spark application. I want to log the above data after each action performed in my program.

Comment: This is getting out of hand, `sc.set("spark.app.id", "myId") would do. You can easily find out that on SO.